# how to handle sequence breaks in db request output

Tags: php, html, arrays, wordpress, output

Hi I'm using a custom base on Wordpress to manage dogs' show results.
My program currently displays the resulting array in a monolithic manner :
[image]

As you can see the first 5 columns are common to multiple dogs.
I'd like to introduce sequence breaks as follows :

Date Location Type

```
 Class 1 Judge
    Dog 1
    Dog n
 Total Dogs in Class

 Class 2 Judge
     Dog 1
     Dog n
 Total Dogs in Class
Total Dogs in Show
```

Below is the code currently used (there may be a few differences with the screen capture).

```
                    foreach ($wpdb->get_results($query)as $row)
                    {
                    print "<tr>";
                    print "<td>" . $row->evt_date . "</td>";
                    print "<td>" . $row->location . "</td>";
                    print "<td>" . $row->type_desc . "</td>";
                    print "<td>" . $row->class_name . "</td>";
                    print "<td>" . $row->civilité . " " . $row->judge_f_name . " " . $row->judge_l_name . "</td>";
                    print "<td>" . $row->position . " " . $row->qualif_descr . "</td>";
                    print "<td>" . $row->dog_name . "</br>" . $row->prod_prop . "</td>";
                    if ($row->CACS_yn == "Y")
                        $distinctions = $distinctions . " CACS ";
                   ...
```

I'd just like to get an idea of how to introduce the sequence breaks and totals.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Add "total per class" in your sql query using a group by (or
   subquery)
2. Ensure that your results are ordered by Class, Dog
3. While iterating in your code, you could keep track of the class you
   just checked and see if the current one is different from the
   previous one.
4. Increment a counter on each iteration to get the total number of
   dogs in the show.